# Android Dialog title alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-styles

How to center vertical the "Login" title?

[image]

This is the style:

```
<style name="ABGAlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/corporativo_red</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyAlertDialogTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogTitle">
    <item name="android:background">@color/corporativo_red</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/corporativo_red</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:bottomOffset">5sp</item>
</style>
```

I've tried `gravity`, `textAlignment` and some others items with no result.

Comment: where do you set the style `MyAlertDialogTitle`?

Comment: Try changing bottom offset to 50sp

Comment: @user if you wants go with custom layout please post you xml file too ..

Comment: see [Custom dialog on Android: How can I center its title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025605/custom-dialog-on-android-how-can-i-center-its-title)

Comment: @DanielZolnai here:
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyAlertDialogTitle</item>

Comment: @Mushroomzier it didnt works.

Comment: @user1140237 the title isnt part of custom layout.

Comment: @pRaNaY it works with center horizontal but not with vertical.

Answer (score 1):

You can't centre a normal alert dialog's title. You will need to create a custom dialog preferably with a dialog fragment or dialog activity depending on the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

Set your text style in the android:textAppearance

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogTitle">
    <item name="android:background">@color/corporativo_red</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/corporativo_red</item>
    <item name="android:bottomOffset">5sp</item>

    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/YourTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

[Change both text and background color in title bar (Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624091/change-both-text-and-background-color-in-title-bar-android)
[Textview: using the dialog title style: @android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492341/textview-using-the-dialog-title-style-androidstyle-textappearance-dialogwind)

Comment: What are you trying to set by android:bottomOffset? Do you mean android:layout_marginBottom?

Answer (score 0):

If Alert dialog is normal without any of your custom layout or theme than you ca get object by passing id with android namespace

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertDialogBuild.setMessage("message text align center");
                alertDialogBuild.setTitle("Title text Align Center");
                alertDialogBuild.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuild.show();
                TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"));
                title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


                TextView message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("message", "id", "android"));
                message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: I would like to do it within style file.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void centerTitleHorizontally(final TextView title)
{
    ViewTreeObserver vto = title.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            try {
                title.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodError x) {
                title.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            title.getPaint().getTextBounds(title.getText().toString(), 0, title.getText().length(), bounds);
            title.setPadding((title.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```